# ¿Cómo agregar nuevos campos en Laravel Jetstream para registro de usuarios?

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Buen dia, he trabajado con laravel jetstream de forma predeterminada, pero ahora me gustaria saber como puedo cambiar, que el login no lo haga con email sino con el nombre de usuario, que archivos deberia configurar?

Es que en la documentación oficial de jetstream muestra algunos archivos que deberian ser cambiados, pero no me queda muy claro.
Tambien me gustaria saber cómo agregar nuevos campos en la tabla users.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambiar la autenticación en la configuración de Jetstream
En el archivo **config/fortify.php**, debes cambiar el valor de la clave ***username*** de `email` a `username`. Así, Jetstream utilizará el nombre de usuario para el inicio de sesión en lugar del correo electrónico.

En el controlador de autenticación **App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController**, debes actualizar el método `attemptLogin()`

```
 return $this->guard()->attempt(
        array_merge($this->credentials($request), ['username' => $request->username]),
        $request->filled('remember')
    );
```

Para agregar nuevos campos a la tabla **users**, debes crear una nueva migración utilizando el comando `make:migration`

```
php artisan make:migration add_new_fields_to_users_table --table=users
```

Luego, dentro del método `up()`, agrega las columnas que deseas agregar a la tabla:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('new_field1');
    $table->string('new_field2');
    // Agrega más campos según lo que necesites
});
```

Finalmente, ejecuta la migración para actualizar la tabla de usuarios:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController, esta ruta no existe, nose si es la nueva version de laravel, trato de buscar el archivo AuthenticatedSessionController pero no aparece, en laravel 10 talvez esta en otra ubicacion ?

Comment: La ruta App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController es creada por Jetstream durante la instalación. Si no la encuentras prueba a: php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views y/o php artisan jetstream:install livewire

Comment: Pudiste resolver el inconveniente? yo ando en busca del controlador o lo que sea de registro, necesito enviar unos datos al formulario de registro. espero puedas ayudarme. Gracias.